# Create a sliding window from a list

Tags: c#, linq

I need to iterate over a list while getting the next and previous Items. I'm currently doing it like so:

```
var items = collection.ToList();
for (int index = 0; index < items.Count; index++)
{
    var prevItem = index == 0 ? null : items[index - 1];
    var currentItem = items[index];
    var nextItem = (index + 1) == items.Count ? null : items[index + 1];
    // do work
}
```

This work but it is not as nice and readable as I would like.  Is there a more readable way of creating a sliding window?  which doesn't involve all of the ugly ternary checks.   I feel like there is a more friendly way using select, skip, take, and default if empty

Comment: what exactly do you perform after getting the previous and next item?

Comment: It is not getting much nicer, as you will have to take care of the "degenerate" cases for index == 0 and index == items.Count-1 in any case. You could perhaps encapsulate the three prev/current/next items in a custom struct/class (including the logic of how to extract them from the collection, or putting this logic in an extension method returning said struct/object) which could make the for loop itself look slightly nicer...

Comment: Sounds like a perfect job for a [LinkedList<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Aominè I'm using it to validate against the current Item against the next and previous.  I need to do this for all the items in the collection

Comment: @elgonzo I feel like there would be a better way using Linq, with a Skip and Take, but i'm a bit sick today and can't think of a better way ATM

Comment: @itsme86 Ooo that just might work thanks

Comment: Even with Skip() and Take() you will have to take special care for index == 0 and index == items.Count-1. It would look not much different from what you have now...

Comment: @johnny5 what do you want as the end result? some elements that meet a certain "criteria" stored in some sort of collection?  some sort of reduce? or simply some sort of `ForEach`?....

Comment: @Aominè I just need the next and previous values when iterating over the list. I do not need to filter or anything I'm just looking for a more efficient readable way of doing the above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of problem is best solved using generators if you want it to be reusable IMHO.

```
public static IEnumerable<(T PrevItem, T CurrentItem, T NextItem)>
        SlidingWindow<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T emptyValue = default)
{
    using (var iter = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iter.MoveNext())
            yield break;
        var prevItem = emptyValue;
        var currentItem = iter.Current;
        while (iter.MoveNext())
        {
            var nextItem = iter.Current;
            yield return (prevItem, currentItem, nextItem);
            prevItem = currentItem;
            currentItem = nextItem;
        }
        yield return (prevItem, currentItem, emptyValue);
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
foreach (var (prevItem, currentItem, nextItem) in collection.SlidingWindow())
{
    // do stuff with prevItem, currentItem, nextItem
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generic window size:

```cs
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CreateSlidingWindow<T>(IEnumerable<T> input, int windowSize)
{
    if (input == null || input.Count() < windowSize)
    {
        return new List<IEnumerable<T>>();
    }
    var first = new[] { input.Take(windowSize) };
    var rest = CreateSlidingWindow(input.Skip(1), windowSize);
    return first.Union(rest);
}
```

Comment: Elegant but recursion will surely overflow for large amounts of data

Answer (score 1):

One way to make it more nicer is to transform your collection in a List of objects which contain the `item`, `prevItem` and `nextItem`:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var collection = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };

            var items = collection.Select((item, index) => new
            {
                Item = item,
                PreVItem = index > 0 ? collection[index - 1] : null,
                NextItem = index < collection.Count-1 ? collection[index + 1] : null
            });

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.PreVItem} \t {item.Item} \t {item.NextItem}");
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Created the following solution that is using an enumerator.

```
public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> SlidingWindowValues<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int windowSize)
{
    var windows = Enumerable.Range(0, windowSize)
        .Select(_ => new List<T>())
        .ToList();

    int i = 0;
    using (var iter = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (iter.MoveNext())
        {
            var c = Math.Min(i + 1, windowSize);
            for (var j = 0; j < c; j++)
            {
                windows[(i - j) % windowSize].Add(iter.Current);
            }
            if (i >= windowSize - 1)
            {
                var previous = (i + 1) % windowSize;
                yield return windows[previous];
                windows[previous] = new List<T>();
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```